# Google App Engine - node.js - server handles all GET/POST requests except first one

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am running a Google App Engine node.js server which is there only to serve GET and POST requests.

The server handles all these GET and POSTS requests perfectly well except the very first one after the application is deployed.

The scaling type is automatic on a F1 instance class.

There is no error in the logs.

I do not get this problem if after the deployment I issue the command "gcloud app browse".

So this looks really like an initial instance problem but I could not find a way to get around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Hugues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer. Two steps are required

1- Include in the app.yaml the following :

automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1

2- Create as pointed out by Daniel (see above) a warmup request

Hope this is useful for someone else :-)

Hugues

Answer (score 1):

The first request to the instance is called a [Loading Request](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed#loading_requests), during this request App Engine undergoes initialization (loading any libraries and resources required to handle the requests) and therefore causing the issues you mention. As mentioned on the aforementioned documentation:

> Load only the code needed for startup.
>
> Access the disk as little as possible.
>
> In some cases, loading code from a zip or jar file is faster than loading from many separate files.

I would also suggest you to configure [Warmup requests to improve the performance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuring-warmup-requests).

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks so much for this. I tried also to setup a warmup request but does not seem it solved the issue. Reading the doc on warmup requests, it is mentioned "Note that warmup requests are not guaranteed to be called." I am not sure how to get around this one.

Comment: Notice that loading requests are intended behavior. Have you tried any of the other methods described? For example you can  modify your app.yaml and include an [entrypoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#entrypoint) to override the [default startup behavior](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#application_startup) and load only the minimum code to handle the requests. Notice that for better performance your `start` script should be as lightweight as possible and it is very dependent to your application needs.